# Multi-platform web based terminal emulator

Tags: shell, web

Is there a web-based terminal emulator compatible with all device like pc browser, smarthphone and tablets (android and iOs)?

I tried shellinabox, but with iOS doesn't work correctly (can't activate the keyboard in Safari browser).

Comment: That doesn't really sound like a `shellinabox` problem. Can you do it w/ a different browser on your phone? Or can you write a little extension that pops the keyboard for you? It's gotta be a simple little command - I can't imagine `shellinabox` would interpret your input any differently to spite the iPhone or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the bug you're talking about? Apparently, there is some code hacking that needs to be done... to make it work.

> I found out that on iPad this.isEmbedded isn't set correctly. It seems that the Mobile Safari doesn't support some attributes for the screen. So this.isEmbedded is set to true, when it shouldn't be.
>   A quick hack:
>   In vt100.js add the following code lines after the first occurence of this.isEmbedded
>
> var isMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad|iPhone|iPod/i) != null;
>   if (isMobile) {
>           this.isEmbedded = false;
>   }
>
> It's only a quick hack;-)
>   It's sad that the iPad keyboard doesn't have a tab key.
>   http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/issues/detail?id=64

Anyhow, for this type of stuff I find that the website http://alternativeto.net/ is great for this. Just type in alternativeto and the program name into your favourite search engine and you normally end up with some other viable alternatives (For instance, TinyShell, KeyBox, Gate One, Onion Terminal, AnyTerm, AjaxTerm, etc...).

http://alternativeto.net/software/shell-in-a-box/